# Multiple instances holds a reference to a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm moving with the times and thought I should start a new project with the goal to use and expose myself to **smart pointers** more. I'm thinking of a large pool of `unique_ptr`s storing collision components. These components will be passed by const ref to a quad tree that internally perform read-only ops on the ptrs.
I've written a simplified example to reflect the intentions of my implementation.

```
struct Owner
{
    unique_ptr<int> uPtr;
};

struct SomeContainer
{
    list<const unique_ptr<int>*> uPtrList;

    void Insert( const unique_ptr<int>& borrowedUPtr )
    {
        list.push_back( &borrowedUPtr );
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        for( const auto& ptr : uPtrList )
            // Perform read ops
    }
};
```

These are my intentions:
`Owner` owns the `unique_ptr` and thereby controls its lifetime. 
`SomeContainer` will store a const reference to the pointer since it's not permitted to neither reset nor modify the pointer in any way. 
 
Is this a viable approach or am I disturbing the force?

Comment: You might as well use `list<int*>` at this point. Unless you are actually more interested by the state of a `unique_ptr` than by the object it's pointing to.

Comment: To me it sounds like owner should have a `std::shared_ptr` and `SomeContainer` should hold `std::weak_ptr`s to those `shared_ptr`s.  I'm not sure if you can get them to be `const` though.

Comment: Your lists contains pointers to unique_ptrs... I don't think that makes much sense. unique_ptr is about ownership. If SomeContainer doesn't own it, better use a const* instead, not a unique_ptr. If you want SomeContainer to share ownership with the original owner, better use shared_ptr

Comment: Why does `Owner` use a `unique_ptr`? `struct Owner{int i;};` already expresses that `Owner` owns the `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two possible solutions.

One of them could be that your owner has a `std::shared_ptr` and `SomeContainer` keep a list of `std::weak_ptr`, something like this:

```
struct Owner
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> uPtr;
};

struct SomeContainer
{
    list<std::weak_ptr<int>> uPtrList;

    void Insert( std::shared_ptr<int> borrowedUPtr )
    {
        list.push_back( std::weak_ptr<int>(borrowedUPtr) );
    }
    //...
};
```

Another one could be that `SomeContainer` keep a list of const raw pointer obtained through `std::unique_ptr::get`. Since Owner has the ownership, if you can guarantee that `Owner` will live as long or longer than `SomeContainer`, there is nothing wrong with such strategy. Personnaly, I prefer this one:

```
struct Owner
{
    unique_ptr<int> uPtr;
};

struct SomeContainer
{
    list<const int*> uPtrList;

    //Could also be directly passed as a const int*
    void Insert( const unique_ptr<int>& borrowedUPtr )
    {
        list.push_back( borrwedUPtr.get() );
    }
    //...
};
```

Comment: In the second case, why own the `int` using a `unique_ptr` why not just an int?

Comment: In the first example, `Insert` should take a `shared_ptr` as input and then construct its own `weak_ptr` from it, eg: `void Insert( std::shared_ptr<int> borrowedUPtr ) { list.push_back( std::weak_ptr (borrowedUPtr) ); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're right. Thanks for pointing this, I changed it.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I did so because he expressed the need for std::unique_ptr. There could be a reason behind this that we are not aware. It could very be a simplified example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think the conversion to a `weak_ptr` is unnecessary. You can `push_back` a `shared_ptr` onto a list of `weak_ptr` fine.

Comment: @ChrisDrew doing so still constructs a `weak_ptr` object. `weak_ptr` has a constructor that takes a `shared_ptr` as input.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sure, it achieves exactly the same, just less typing.

Comment: Your second solution is actually what my first gut feeling approach was. I was however discouraged from it after reading some opinions on "multiple objects accessing the pointee of an `unique_ptr`" being bad design and "never use `.get()` on a smart pointer. Sometimes one can easily be swayed by other programmers with more seniority in terms of the SO reward system and this is especially true for me, being a Padawan. +1 for two sound solutions.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear why you need to use smart pointers here at all. A simple member variable expresses ownership just fine:

```
struct Owner
{
    int value;
};
```

And then observers can store a raw-pointer:

```
struct SomeContainer
{
    list<const int*> ptrList;

    void Insert( const int& borrowedValue)
    {
        ptrList.push_back( &borrowedValue);
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        for( const auto& ptr : ptrList)
            // Perform read ops
    }
};
```

This is assuming you can be confident that owner will stay alive whilst the observers wish to observe. If you can't be confident of that then `unique_ptr` will not help you and you will need some something like `weak_ptr` with `shared_ptr`.

Comment: I wanted to expose myself to smart pointers more and this I an isolated project with the sole purpose of learning. Perhaps it was a poor choice to use `int` instead of `<T>` but this was highly simplified for the sake of SO. This need to be a pointer because the type isn't known at compile time. I've accepted another answer but I will give you a +1 for giving a sound alternative solution and for contributing to the discussion as whole.